# include_HEADERS and no rule for target needed by 'all-am'

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to compile a library with autotools. The library compiles fine with the following Makefile.am in its source directory library/src

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libgtkchart.la

libgtkchart_la_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -Wall $(gtk_CFLAGS) 
libgtkchart_la_LIBADD =  $(gtk_LIBS) $(glib_LIBS)
libgtkchart_la_LDFLAGS = -fPIC -shared -version-info 1:0:0
libgtkchart_la_SOURCES = gtkchart.c gtkaxis.c gtkbarchart.c gtkchartdata.c gtkchart.h gtkaxis.h gtkbarchart.h gtkbarchartdata.h
```

but if I add the following line to that file:

```
include_HEADERS = gtkaxis.h gtkbarchart.h gtkbarchartdata.h gtkchart.h
```

I get the following error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'gtkbarchartdata.h', needed by 'all-am'.  Stop.
```

My main MAkefile.am in library/ is

```
SUBDIRS = src
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS= -I m4
```

and my configure.ac is

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])
AC_INIT([library], [1.0], [me])
AM_PROG_AR
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_DISABLE_STATIC
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([ 
Makefile
src/Makefile
])
LT_INIT
AC_OUTPUT
```

I can't figure out why the need for a target for that header file.

Answer (score 0):

> When you assign header files to the `include_HEADERS`, automake must
>   be able to locate the header.

**For example,** if you have the following directory structure:

```
src
   Makefile.am
   GTKBarCharDataDirectory
   SomeOtherDirectory
   gtkaxis.h
   gtkbarchart.h
   gtkchart.h
```

And gtkbarchartdata.h is located in the GTKBarCharDataDirectory directory, then you need to change your include_Headers to be:

```
include_HEADERS = gtkaxis.h gtkbarchart.h GTKBarCharDataDirectory/gtkbarchartdata.h gtkchart.h
```

make must know the relative path of the header file, when using the include_Headers variable. This is due to the fact that the HEADER family of variables works differently than the SOURCES family of variables.

> automake won't fail if you list a non-existent/not-found header file
>   in the libgtkchart_la_SOURCES variable, since `Header files listed in
>   a _SOURCES definition will be included in the distribution but
>   otherwise ignored.`

Check [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-Sources.html) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Headers.html) for a reference

Comment: My directory structure is very simple and all source files and header files are in the same directory as Makefile.am This must not be the culprit